# Is this expression $7x – 2y + 4z = 7x + 2(-y) + 4z$ right?

Tags: linear-algebra

$7x – 2y + 4z  = 7x + 2(-y) + 4z$

Is above expression right I am stuck with a problem ,by using this(above) expression  I am getting ambiguous  answers but when I use different way i.e $7x – 2y + 4z =7x + (-2)y + 4z$  i get correct answers but question arises in mind that why this $7x – 2y + 4z  = 7x + 2(-y) + 4z$ is not correct

Comment: In any field or ring the two expressions are the same. So we need your detailed calculations to see what is wrong.

Comment: @Emilio Novati No this is just a linear equation I stuck at it when I was finding the graphical solutions of $ 7x - 2y + 4z $.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The opposit of $y$ is, by definition, the element $-y$ such that $-y+y=0$.

Now use distributivity: $(-1\times y)+(1\times y)=(-1+1)\times y= 0\times y=0$
so you have that $(-1\times y)$ is the opposite of $1 \times y=y$ , i.e. $-1 \times y = -y$ .

Now write $2 \times (-y) $ as $ 2 \times ((-1)\times y)$ and use associativity and you have $-2 \times y=2 \times (-y)$

Comment: Relatively good answer.

Comment: maybe i've not well understood the question?